# how to solve BeanCreationExceptrion error?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I try to develop some server program using spring4 and jackrabbit. When i test the Controller class using JUnit, BeanCreationExceptrion error is occurs. I think this error associated with autowired variable. help me. how to solve this problem?

This is head of my Controller class.

```
package kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.model.RDML;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.model.Traceability;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLConverter;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLDBMgmt;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLRDFMgmt;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.RDMLDBException;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.RDMLRDFException;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.RevisionControlException;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.rdf.RDFConverter;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;

// reference
// http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/
@Controller
public class SoremoreController {

    private static final int buffer_size = 1024;
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SoremoreController.class.getName());
    private static String fileName = "";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext  = null;

    @Autowired
    private IRDMLConverter rdmlConverter  = null;

    @Autowired
    private IRDMLRDFMgmt rdmlRDFMgmt  = null;

    @Autowired
    private IRDMLDBMgmt rdmlDBMgmt = null;

    @Autowired
    private RDFConverter rdfConverter  = null;
....
```

This is my test class.

```
package kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.model.RDML;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.model.Traceability;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.RDMLDBException;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/soremore-servlet.xml" })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/application-config.xml" })
public class SoremoreControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    SoremoreController soremoreController = null;

    @Test
    public void storeRDML() {
//      String[] hwpmlPaths = { "resource/sample_rdml/예제 1.xml",
//              "resource/sample_rdml/예제 2.xml",
//              "resource/sample_rdml/예제 3.xml",
//              "resource/sample_rdml/예제 4.xml",
//              "resource/sample_rdml/예제 5.xml",
//              "resource/sample_rdml/예제 6.xml",
//              "resource/sample_rdml/예제 7.xml",
//              "resource/sample_rdml/예제 8.xml",
//              "resource/sample_rdml/예제 9.xml",
//              "resource/sample_rdml/예제 10.xml" };
//
//      for (String hwpmlPath : hwpmlPaths) {
//          soremoreController.storeRDML(hwpmlPath);
//      }

        ArrayList<RDML> rdmls = loadTestRDML();
        boolean isSuccessful = false;
        for (RDML rdml : rdmls) {
            try {
                soremoreController.storeRDML(rdml);
                System.out.println();
                isSuccessful = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                isSuccessful = false;
            }
        }
        Assert.assertTrue(isSuccessful);
    }

    @Test
    public void storeRDMLWithTraceability() throws IOException {
        List<RDML>rdmls = null ;
        String previousRDMLId = "xxx";

        for (RDML rdml : rdmls) {
            soremoreController.storeRDMLWithTraceability(rdml,
                    previousRDMLId, TraceabilityTypes.satisfy);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void updateRDMLWithTraceability() {
        String previousRDMLId1 = "xxx";
        String previousRDMLId2 = "xxx";

        String updatedTraceability = soremoreController.updateRDMLTraceability(
                previousRDMLId1, previousRDMLId2, TraceabilityTypes.satisfy);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteRDMLWithTraceability() {
        String previousRDMLId1 = "xxx";
        String previousRDMLId2 = "xxx";

        String removedTraceability = soremoreController.deleteRDMLTraceability(
                previousRDMLId1, previousRDMLId2);
    }

    @Test
    public void searchRDML() {
        String rdmlKeyWord = "abc";

        ArrayList<RDML> rdmls = soremoreController.searchRDML(rdmlKeyWord);
        for (RDML rdml : rdmls) {
            System.out.println(rdml);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void searchRDML0() {
        String rdmlKeyWord = "def";

        ArrayList<RDML> rdmls = soremoreController.searchRDML(rdmlKeyWord);
        for (RDML rdml : rdmls) {
            System.out.println(rdml);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void searchRDML1() {
        String rdmlKeyWord = "2차년도계획서";

        ArrayList<RDML> rdmls = soremoreController.searchRDML(rdmlKeyWord);
        for (RDML rdml : rdmls) {
            System.out.println(rdml);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void getRDML() {
        String rdmlID = "abc";
        RDML rdml = soremoreController.getRDML(rdmlID);
    }

    @Test
    public void getParentIDs() {
        String rdmlID = "abcd";

        ArrayList<String> parentIDs = soremoreController.getParentIDs(rdmlID);

        for (String string : parentIDs) {

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void getChildIDs() {
        String rdmlID = "abcd";

        ArrayList<String> childIDs = soremoreController.getChildIDs(rdmlID);

        for (String string : childIDs) {

        }
    }

    public void getDirectLinkedTraceability() {
        String rdmlID = "abcd";
        ArrayList<Traceability> linkedTraceabilities = soremoreController
                .getDirectLinkedTraceability(rdmlID);

        for (Traceability traceability : linkedTraceabilities) {

        }

    }

    public ArrayList<RDML> loadTestRDML() {
        ArrayList<RDML> rdmls = new ArrayList<RDML>();
        String xmlSource = "resource/sample_rdml";

        File sourceDir = new File(xmlSource);
        File[] sourceFiles = sourceDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : sourceFiles) {
            RDML rdml = new RDML();
            rdml.setRdmlAsDocument(createDocument(file));
            rdmls.add(rdml);
        }

        return rdmls;
    }

    private Document createDocument(File rdmlPathAsFile) {
        SAXBuilder jdomBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document jdomDocument = null;
        try {
            jdomDocument = jdomBuilder.build(rdmlPathAsFile);
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jdomDocument;
    }
}
```

This is my spring configuration xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </bean>



    <!-- for file upload -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20000000" />

    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is head of class of one variable.

```
package kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.rdml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.NodeIterator;
import javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException;
import javax.jcr.Repository;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials;
import javax.jcr.UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException;
import javax.jcr.ValueFormatException;
import javax.jcr.lock.LockException;
import javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException;
import javax.jcr.nodetype.NoSuchNodeTypeException;
import javax.jcr.query.Query;
import javax.jcr.query.QueryManager;
import javax.jcr.query.QueryResult;
import javax.jcr.version.Version;
import javax.jcr.version.VersionException;
import javax.jcr.version.VersionHistory;
import javax.jcr.version.VersionIterator;
import javax.jcr.version.VersionManager;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller.SoremoreController;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.model.RDML;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.IRDMLDBMgmt;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.RDMLDBException;
import kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.service.RevisionControlException;

import org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jdom2.Attribute;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RDMLDBMgmtImpl implements IRDMLDBMgmt {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SoremoreController.class.getName());
    static private int docNumber = 0;
    private Repository repository;
    private Session session;
....
```

This is stacktrace.

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller.SoremoreControllerTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller.SoremoreController kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller.SoremoreControllerTest.soremoreController; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller.SoremoreController] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:385)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:82)
 at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:199)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:253)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller.SoremoreController kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller.SoremoreControllerTest.soremoreController; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller.SoremoreController] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
 ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller.SoremoreController] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
 ... 28 more
```

Comment: Where is th stacktrace?

Comment: oh... sorry i'll attach that.

Comment: Maye this is not correct: `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/application-config.xml" })` i think it must be `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/application-config.xml" })
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Spring to autowire the SoremoreController field in your test case it needs a bean definition in the ApplicationContext for a bean of that type. That means you need to component-scan the package (or a parent package) where the SoremoreController is defined in the xml file you point out in the ContextConfiguration annotation.

Note that **all** autowired fields in SoremoreController instance must also have corresponding beans defined in the ApplicationContext, otherwise Spring will not be able to create that instance, causing your test to fail with stacktraces similar to the one you posted (but always explicitly pointing out - towards the end - the root cause of the problem).

Comment: Though i already put the @Controller annotation in the SoremoreController class, should i add bean definition in the application-config.xml?

Comment: If there is a Controller annotation in the SoremoreController class you don't need to create a separate bean definition in the XML file. But you need to make sure that the Controller class resides in a sub-package of "kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore" (the package pointed out in the component-scan definition).

Comment: Yes, SoremoreController in the package "kr.ac.jbnu.sql.soremore.controller". However, above error occurs... I don't know what should i do.

Comment: Are you certain that you are pointing out the correct XML file? I.e.: is the xml configuration file in your question located at /src/main/resources/application-config.xml

Comment: sure! and sorry i see this comment too late.